# How to handle "if context menu is cancelled" with Javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, contextmenu

I am trying to implement a system to mask affiliated links of a web page.
I can handle user's right click with `oncontextmenu` event and mask the link without any problem
but when user cancels context menu, link value is been changed.

```
link.oncontextmenu = function () {
     link.href = "http://......";          
}
```

I cannot find a way to handle when user cancel context menu to change link's value into its original value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such event for canceling context menu.
You can handle it using onmousedown.

Comment: I defined onmousedown event(window.onmousedown = func..) in oncontextmenu event function. I can handle events when user click anywhere in window except user clicks on context menu (eg. "open in new tab")